# 2 X server desktops, want to close each screen on command

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome

I have a laptop that's running Ubuntu (gnome)
 and to it there's a screen connected. 
Now in the properties I have it set to Seperate X screen, 
and now I want to know how do I make one of them close by a command. 
So it wouldn't actually exit anything but only close a certain screen (not both).

Comment: What do you mean by closing a screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to "turn off display", you need the following magic word: **xrandr**!

```
$ xrandr --output CRT2 --off
```

This could have been named "screen_control" or "monitor_tools", but xrandr it is.

Comment: CRT2 not found, is there a way to get a list of the screen names?

Comment: Either xrandr -q or maybe man xrandr